# ZSH: `ls *(.)` lists regular files only but `ls *(/)` does not list directories only

Tags: zsh, ls

I'm not sure I am using ZSH's globbing correctly, but I thought `ls *(/)` would just list the dirctories under `pwd`, but it doesn't, it recursively lists all files under every directory under `pwd` (I got the statement from [this](http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/tips/zshtips.html) list of useful zsh tips)

What would be right globbing for exclusively listing the directories under my current path?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect the problem is not the zsh globbing, but the `ls` default behavior, that when given a directory argument list the content of directory.

I suggest to try

```
ls -d -- <your-glob-here>
```

The best way to test your globs is with

```
printf '%s\n' <glob>
```

or

```
print -rC1 -- <glob>
```

Comment: Another way to test globs with zsh is to tab-expand them. That’ll replace the glob with all matched paths.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to achieve it is

```
 print *(/)
```

or

```
 echo *(/)
```

**Update1**

A bit *more* correct version (as noted by @Stéphane Chazelas) would be

```
print -rl -- *(/)
```

or

```
echo -E - *(/)
```

to take care about spaces (-l), escape sequences (-r/-E) and leading hyphens (--/-) inside filenames.

**Update2**

Yet *even more* correct version is `print -rN` which additionally takes care of linebreaks inside filenames (linux allows them, windows doesn't) by separating the results with nulls, for example:

```
print -rN -- **/*(/) |xargs -0 -n10 chmod g+s
```

which recursively sets setguid bit - selectively addressing directories, as opposed to `chmod -R g+s`.

**Update3**

For huge trees this only processes a part of files (due to the limit on command line length) and silently leave the rest as is. The following commands can handle this situation:

```
find . -type d -print0 |xargs -0 -n10 chmod g+s
```

Comment: Should be `print -rl -- *(/)` or `echo -E - *(/)`. Without `-r/-E`, `print`/`echo` expand escape sequences. The `-l` option to `print` prints one argument per line. See also `-c` (optionally with `-a`) to print in columns

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Totally agree. I only use those without options if I created the files myself. That might not be secure enough, though.

Answer (score -1):

To list all directories in the current directory type

```
ls -d -- *(/)
ls -d *(/)
```

Otherwise use

```
ls -d */**(/)
```

to list all directories recursivley.