# Glob character within variable expands in bash but not zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards, variable-substitution

I'm seeing an issue with zsh where a glob character within a variable is not expanding as I would expect. The following example does a better job of explaining it.

```
$ echo $0
-bash

$ echo $HOME/Downloads/zsh-test/*
/Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file1 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file2 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file3 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file4

$ file=*; echo $HOME/Downloads/zsh-test/$file
/Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file1 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file2 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file3 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file4

Macbook% echo $0
zsh

Macbook% echo $HOME/Downloads/zsh-test/*
/Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file1 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file2 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file3 /Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/file4

Macbook% file=*; echo $HOME/Downloads/zsh-test/$file
/Users/bruce/Downloads/zsh-test/*
```

I would have expected the last command to expand like it does in bash. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What was your current working directory when you ran each of those commands?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That would be the first time I see anybody complaining about that (we more often see people complaining about it not doing word splitting upon parameter expansion).

Most people expect

```
echo $file
```

to output the content of the `$file` variable and are annoyed when shells like `bash` don't (a behaviour inherited from the Bourne shell, unfortunately not fixed by ksh and specified by POSIX for the `sh` interpreter), and that's causing a lot of bugs and security vulnerabilities and that's why you need to quote all the variables in those shells.

See for instance: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

I see that you're expecting that too as you're writing `echo $0` and not `echo "$0"`.

`zsh` has fixed that. It does neither globbing nor word splitting by default upon parameter expansion. You need to request those explicitly:

- `echo $=file`: perform word splitting
- `echo $~file`: perform globbing
- `echo $=~file`: perform both

Or you could turn on the `globsubst` and `shwordsplit` options to get the same behaviour as in Bourne-like shells (those two options are enabled when `zsh` is invoked as `sh` for `sh` compatibility), but I would not recommend that unless you need `zsh` to interpret code written for another shell (and even in that case, it would make more sense to interpret that code in `sh` emulation in a local context with `emulate -L sh`).

Here naming your variable `file` in

```
file=*
```

is misleading if you intend it to be expanded upon expansion¹

```
filename_pattern=*
```

would make more sense. If you want a variable holding the name of all the non-hidden files in the current directory, you'd do:

```
files=(*)
```

or:

```
files=(*(N))
```

for that assignment not to fail if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory.

That is, use an *array* variable assignment. That (`file=(*)`) would work the same as in `bash` or `ksh93`, `mksh` or `yash`, except that `zsh` doesn't have that other misfeature of the Bourne shell whereby the pattern is left unexpanded when there's no match.

---

<sup>¹Note that `*` is a perfectly valid name for a file on Unix-like system. I take some comfort in that `rm -f -- $file` removes the file whose name is stored in `$file` even if that file is called `*`.</sup>

Comment: Learnt a lot from this answer. Thanks. 

I really boiled this question down for simplicity. I am actually trying to loop through files in a directory with some wildcard matching, in a script that must work in bash and zsh. I'll post that as a separate question.

Comment: @BruceJohnson https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38172/switching-to-zsh-are-all-bash-scripts-compatible-with-zsh/38183#38183

Comment: In the file pattern example, isnt that glob expanded and assigned to file_pattern by bash? Before it ever gets expanded by $file_pattern?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, no. Try `f=*; echo "$f"` in `bash`. That's an assignment to a scalar variable, which can contain only one value. You'd need `f=(*)` as shown, that is do an array variable assignment for a variable to contain any number of values.