# Usig zsh glob variable not expanding inside alias

Tags: zsh, wildcards, alias

I want to list and sort by time, all the files matching a certain pattern and then get only the first 20:

```
ls -laths *.txt | head -20
```

This works well, for example if I create two files:

```
touch 1.txt
touch 2.txt
```

The result of the above command is:

```
$ ls -laths *.txt | head -20
1,5K -rw-rw---- 1 user user 0 20. Apr 09:49 2.txt
1,5K -rw-rw---- 1 user user 0 20. Apr 09:49 1.txt
```

This works well if I do it on the terminal. But when trying to save it as an alias (where the input $1 is the pattern I want), like this:

```
alias lis20='function _(){ ls -laths "${1}" | head -20; }; _'
```

Then when I use the alias, I get:

```
$ lis20 *.txt
1,5K -rw-rw---- 1 user user 0 20. Apr 09:49 1.txt
```

It means it only lists the first file.
I have tried several expansions of the variable inside, as in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461360/glob-character-within-variable-expands-in-bash-but-not-zsh), but without any success.

I am using zsh, but it would be nice to have a solution that works for both bash and zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are text expansion, so with `lis20 *.txt` the alias is first expanded to

```
function _(){ ls -laths "${1}" | head -20; }; _ *.txt
```

and then filename generation turns the function call into

```
_ abc.txt def.txt etc.txt
```

so in the function, `$1` contains only the first matching filename.

Now, you could fix that by using `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` in the function instead... (`"$@"` is magic: despite the quotes, it expands into multiple words, all the arguments separately and intact.)

But then, you don't really need a function *and* an alias anyway. Just make it a single function:

```
lis20() {
    ls -laths "$@" | head -20
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was a very helpful reply. For some reason, I didn't know I can define functions and use them on their own in my `.bashrc`. I always had them associated with an alias.

Comment: @Santiago, `.bashrc` is just a script, you can do basically anything there that you could do with the shell elsewhere. Including e.g. starting `ssh-agent`. Just avoid printing output, some automatic tools (like `scp`) can break with that.