# How to make my bash terminal remember commands

Tags: bash, command-history

I am currently using Parrot Security.  However, in Kali when I would issue commands in my terminal it would remember them and when I would go to type another command in my terminal that was similar it would prompt me to see if I wanted to use a previous command kind of like spell check.  You can also scroll through the commands using the arrow keys.  So I was just wondering if there is a way I can make my terminal in parrot do the same thing?  Thanks for any help

- shell: `/bin/bash`
- Histsize=1000
- Histfile `/home/legionaire/.bash_history`

I can open the bash history file and see all my commands. I just like in Kali how it comes up as you type something similar and you can scroll with the arrows.

Comment: What shell are you using? `echo $SHELL`. Read the `man` page of your shell (`man ${SHELL##*/}`, about "Command History". What are "`echo "HISTSIZE=$HISTSIZE, HISTFILE=$HISTFILE"? [Edit] your question to reply, don't reply via comment. Not saving command history could be seen as a "security feature". I'm unfamiliar with Parrot Security.

Comment: What you're looking for is zsh-autosuggestions. Switch to zsh and install zsh-autosuggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, you need to change your shell to zsh and install zsh-autosuggestions. First, install zsh and git with `sudo apt-get install zsh git`. Next run `chsh` and when prompted type `/bin/zsh`. Thirdly type `git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions` to clone the zsh-autosuggestions repo. Finally type `echo "source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh" >> ~/.zshrc` and either type `source ~/.zshrc` or start a new shell after that.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a [custom shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109366/does-bash-have-similar-features-such-as-fishs-autosuggestions-and-highlighting):**
You can change your default shell to one that provides this kind of feature: [Fish shell](https://fishshell.com/) or ZSH with the [zsh-autosuggestion](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) addon. Be aware that [shells are different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/983/what-features-are-in-zsh-and-missing-from-bash-or-vice-versa), changing your shell to [Fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html) or [ZSH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh/361957#361957) might change some of your commands or [scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38172/are-all-bash-scripts-compatible-with-zsh) behaviour.

**Search with Ctrl-R:** If you can't change your shell (or if you don't want to), you can search your history using Crtl-R. This is different from the on-the-fly completion you are looking for, but can be an useful alternative. See [How to cycle through reverse-i-search in BASH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/how-to-cycle-through-reverse-i-search-in-bash).

Comment: Someone said to use CTRL-R which works however, when I reboot the PC everything that was there is gone, is there anyway I can change this

Comment: @Rideboards did you try following the instructions I gave?

Comment: @Grace Thompson  No, I had not tried that yet.  CTRL-R served my purpose until I found out that it did not remember after reboot.  I will give it a try here shortly.  Thank you.